# Role of "kauditd_printk_skb" in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-16.04

I got this in my "dmesg" output:

```
kauditd_printk_skb: 10 callbacks suppressed
```

Can someone enlighten me on this "kauditd_printk_skb"?   Essentially what does it do and how do I enumerate all the 10 callbacks which it has suppressed?  And perhaps the reasons that goes with it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Linux uses this mechanism to throttle the spamming of log events, decreasing the likelihood of a denial-of-service attack.

You can find tune this feature by amending two settings `net.core.message_burst` and `net.core.message_cost`.

> These parameters  are used to limit the warning messages written to the kernel
>     log from  the  networking  code.  They  enforce  a  rate  limit  to  make  a
>     denial-of-service attack  impossible. A higher message_cost factor, results in
>     fewer messages that will be written. Message_burst controls when messages will
>     be dropped.  The  default  settings  limit  warning messages to one every five
>     seconds.

To check their current values use:

`sudo sysctl -a | grep net.core.message_`

To amend them:

`sysctl -w net.core.message_cost=0`

Please note that disabling this mechanism is not recommend in production environments.

More information:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/net.txt

Comment: Are you sure the kaudit messages are from the networking code (and use `net.core.message_cost`) and not general `kernel.printk_ratelimit_burst`?

Comment: @Marki555 is correct, I reduced spammy log messages by increasing `kernel.printk_ratelimit` and `kernel.printk_ratelimit_burst` to higher values. Changing `net.core.message_cost` didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I saw the same thing when I was playing around with dmesg. Documentation is sparse, but I managed to find [this webpage](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1666644) that suggests it's not an issue. Evidently is just means that the kernel is rate limiting messages.